# Do I need an airport transit visa through Switzerland if I have a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, egyptian-citizens

I am Egyptian citizen holding a single entry visa to Spain , travelling in 1 July but i will have 1 day transit in Swiss airport , so do i need a visa to enter Switzerland ?

Comment: @Karlson: actually not, this one is way more clear cut

Comment: Actually still duplicate but of the different question

Comment: @Karlson: you're right.

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate. The other question is specifically for single entry Schengen visa.

Comment: The situation is the same as http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14692/can-i-travel-to-paris-for-a-day-with-a-single-entry-visa-for-schengen-from-switz (which should have been picked as a duplicate). Your Schengen visa is good for entering Schengen at any place, including Switzerland on your way to Spain and back.

Answer (score 3):

No you don't. Switzerland is in the Schengen zone, that will be your point of entry into Schengen. Your further flight from Switzerland to Spain is a flight inside Schengen zone, which means no passport checks by immigrations/customs.

Comment: thank you for your answer but my visa i applied is from Spain embassy which is my main point of destination that i have to enter first soi want to know it will be ok if i enter swiss first before Spain ?

Comment: @momo17: No, you don't have to enter Spain first. You can enter Schengen zone at any place. That question has been answered on this site numerous time already.