# Travelling on a single entry Schengen visa

Tags: visas, france, schengen, customs-and-immigration, germany

I have a Schengen visa single entry valid for 60 days.I intend on spending a month in France then taking a flight from Nice through Barcelona to Munich, Germany. Is that possible with this type of visa?

Answer (score 0):

There are two sides to it:

Single Entry VISA is applicable to only a single entry to/between Schenghen countries. The whole point behind Schengen scheme is that one visa for all. When it comes to single entry, any visa allows you to use it for a single trip. This also holds true for Schengen territory. You can get the Schenghen from French Embassy showing that you are going to Germany, NO PROBLEM. You can finish your trip to Germany and choose to visit France, Italy, Portugal, NO PROBLEM. But at any point, if you decide to leave Schenghen territory (e.g. go back to the UK) your single entry visa is not valid anymore.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a duplicate question and your answer is wrong

Comment: Wrong Answer...

Comment: Could you please tell us what's wrong?

Comment: @MarcelC. read the answer here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14692/can-i-travel-to-paris-for-a-day-with-a-single-entry-visa-for-schengen-from-switz

Comment: @HaLaBi         I have expanded my answer. It was not really a wrong answer but needed further clarification. i expanded it now and it should be more than enough

Comment: @MarcelC. Take a look at the answer prior to edit.

Comment: Ok I will do that