# Can I enter Schengen through Athens and leave through Rome?

Tags: visas, schengen

Can I enter Schengen area through Athens, Greece and leave through Rome with the Schengen Visa?

Comment: point of clarification since the link did not satisfy my question: can I leave through rome, italy on my way to my home country having entered through athens greece?

Comment: If you're able to receive a visa from one country and travel to [any other with the covered area](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14692/can-i-travel-to-paris-for-a-day-with-a-single-entry-visa-for-schengen-from-switz?rq=1) and if need be enter, stay, and leave the country that didn't issue you visa within the area, why would there be a concern?

Comment: To answer your question more directly: Yes, you can.