# Single entry visa with stop-over

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen

I have a single entry visa to Spain from Abu Dhabi via Brussels. Flight from Abu Dhabi to Brussels is with Etihad airways and from Brussels to Barcelona is with Ryan Air. Knowing that I am changing the airline, and I need to collect my luggage upon arrival to Brussels, am I allowed to pass the passport control to collect my luggage and enter again from the passport control to take the flight to Barcelona?
The same scenario is for the return flight, I have a long stopover am I allowed to get out of the airport? I am worried that this may not be considered as a single entry?

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: For intra-Schengen flights, there should be no passport checks in general. But I'm not sure if there aren't any exceptions to this rule. Also, have your boarding pass or flight reservation for the Brussels-Barcelona leg ready before going through the passport check in Brussels, as they may want to see some evidence for the fact that you applied for the visa with the right embassy.

Comment: I have a Lebanese nationality

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I travel to Paris for a day with a single entry visa for Schengen from Switzerland?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14692/can-i-travel-to-paris-for-a-day-with-a-single-entry-visa-for-schengen-from-switz)

Comment: As Belgium and Spain are both Schengen members, your itinerary constitutes a single entry into the "territory of the member states" of the Schengen area (this is the term used in the legal code).  The only problem would be if your visa is restricted in territorial validity.  What does it say under "valid for"?

Answer (score 2):

The flights between Brussels and Barcelona are intra-Schengen flights, so you will not go through passport check (as already mentioned in the comments). You will enter the Schengen zone only once (in Brussel) so your single-entry visa is enough for your trip.

In Brussels you can get out of the airport, I see no problem.