# Hungary Schengen visa, Austria query

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry, austria, hungary

I plan to apply for a tourist visa for Hungary. It will be a Schengen visa. Out of a trip of 6 days, I plan to spend one night in Vienna (Austria) and the rest of the trip in Hungary.

The point of entry and exit will be Hungary.

I will be mentioning in the Schengen visa application form "Hungary and Austria" under the member states of destination.

If I opt for a single entry Hungary Schengen tourist visa, and if I leave for Vienna, will I be allowed back into Hungary? Or is it once you leave a country you cannot go back to it unless it is 2-times entry or multiple-entry visa.

Sorry for this detailed question, and may sound like a noob, but I wanted to check. I am an Indian national and will be travelling from India.

Comment: There are no border checks between Hungary and Austria. There is noone to allow or deny you on the border. Once inside the Schengen zone you go wherever you please (as long as your visa is valid). That's what the Schengen zone means. (What a world we live in, I remember when it was a privilege for Hungarians to cross that border, only once every three years, and now the border station is just deserted. The feeling is indescribable.)

Comment: @chx he might be referring to Hungary's having closed its border as a result of the migrant crisis. If the OP is challenged at a closed border and has a spent single entry, things could get awkward.

Comment: Isn't that a single entry into the Schengen area?

Comment: @chx, yes, but I can't see any other grounds for the OP's question other than he contemplates a closed border within Schengen.

Comment: @GayotFow other grounds for the question include confusion. It wouldn't be the first time. http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/14692/19400

Answer (score 4):

No, single entry Schengen Visa will give you one single entry for whole Schengen Area, for the days mentioned on visa sticker. You may freely move around Schengen provided you are within the dates, days & purpose allowed on this visa. Keep in mind that few EU countries are not Schengen members, like Croatia; few Schengen members are not EU members, like (Switzerland), few countries geographically situated in Europe are neither in EU nor in Schengen, like Andorra, thanks to Henning) So, you can/may stay/roam in whole exact Schengen area only.

Borders between Austria and Hungary might be closed because of "migrant" situation, but all they check is if you have required visa/documents. So landing in Budapest, then going to Vienna, and coming back to Budapest will not be counted as any exit from Schengen Area. Hungary and Austria are still members of Schengen, and are still honouring these visas.

As you are Indian, (I am also), think Schengen Area and members as India and its states (only for C Type visa). There maybe a strict border-checking at certain state borders, and at few other border crossings, there maybe just a change in road surface.

Also, the Paper Visa Form has not much space to write multiple countries in destination field. So, the formula of choosing destination (& thus embassy) is:

- in which member state you will spend most of your planned days, no matter you entered or exited anywhere else? This willbe your destination.
- if you will spend same number of days in two or more member states, then the first member state will be your destination for visa form purpose.

As few embassies use online form for visa application, they give you choice of selecting only one member state as destination.

Point of entry or member state of entry will be your first landing airport in schengen area, no matter how short is the transit. In first few applications I did not know this, and thought I will stay air side in my schengen transits, and will "enter" into schengen only at last final destination airport, but was wrong. As soon as you touch down in Schengen, you are in from that airport/country. For KLM fligjts, its AMS/Netherlands most of the time.

Edit:
Excerpt from [France Embassy in USA](http://www.consulfrance-washington.org/spip.php?article384), on whether one should apply to them for Tourist Schengen Visa (of course if applicant is applying from USA)

> You have to apply with a French Consulate, if :
>
> - You wish to go only to France ;
> - You wish to travel to several Schengen States, but France is the country where you are going to spend most of the time of your trip ;
> - You wish to travel to several Schengen States, with no main destination (the duration of your stay is strictly equal in each country), but France is your first point of entry.

Comment: Nice answer. A small nitpick: strictly speaking, the country competent to adjudicate the visa application is the *main destination,* if there is one. Generally, the main destination is determined by duration of stay, but *not necessarily.* If the principle purpose of the trip is to attend a conference, for example, it could be possible to determine the main destination without regard to time spent. This concept is by its nature somewhat flexible, so it's possible (if not likely) that different consulates will apply it differently.

Comment: Thanks :) yes, agree, in the end it all depends on the consulates, my all experiences are from the ones in Doha. Spain & Hungary processed my applixations, even though I wrote Madrid & Budapest as entry points, transit through AMS both times, but Austrian one made me refill the form & book another appointment after changing it to AMS, heading for Vienna.

Comment: @phoog I think this formula is fairly documnted in Schengen Visa Codes & Rules, that one embassy will accept application only when; either you visit that country only; or you spend more number of days there as compared to other countries; or you enter that country first from the list of countries you spend the same number of days.

Comment: @phoog example case. One visits France only? French Embassy. One visits france for three days and one in italy two in german? French embassy. One lands in Holland, same day arrives in France for three days, three days in Germany, one in Italy? French Embassy.

Comment: Sure, most of the examples have to do with length of stay, but it is explicitly not the only criterion: "if the visit includes more than one destination, the Member State whose territory constitutes the main destination of the visit(s) in terms of the length ***or purpose*** of stay" (emphasis added). And I am sure I've seen at least one example in the guidance to illustrate the principle of purpose as opposed to length.

Comment: @phoog agreed, especially in business visit..

Comment: @Davinder: _Angora_ is a former spelling of the Turkish capital Ankara, which is definitely outside Schengen. You mean _Andorra_, a microstate bordering Spain and France, which is neither in the EU nor in Schengen member. Non-EU members in Schengen include Switzerland, Liechtenstein, Norway, and Iceland.