# Can I visit Amsterdam and Paris on a single-entry Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, paris, amsterdam

This is my first time to plan a trip. I'm going to visit Amsterdam and then go to Paris. Will my single-entry Schengen tourist visa allow for my planned trip?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I travel to Paris for a day with a single entry visa for Schengen from Switzerland?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14692/can-i-travel-to-paris-for-a-day-with-a-single-entry-visa-for-schengen-from-switz)

Comment: @pnuts the obvious solution is to edit he Switzerland question to replace all references to France with "a Schengen country" and those to Switzerland with "another Schengen country."

Comment: @pnuts I doubt Joel would support the notion that we should entertain separate questions for every possible permutation of multiple-country Schengen itinerary on a single-entry visa.

Answer (score 7):

Of course, the Schengen Area works as a single country for border purposes. A single entry visa allows for one entry into the area, and you're free to move within it during the validity period of your visa.

Your passport will not normally be checked at the Dutch-Belgian or Belgian-French border. If it happens, it's just an internal check to see that everyone's legally in Europe, and no stamps are given.

Comment: Nitpick: France and the Nederlands don't share a border (in continental Europe)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it will be permitted. Your passport will not be checked on your journey from Amsterdam to Paris. (Sometimes, there can be a check for drugs on the border)

Comment: Your passport may be checked by the operator of your mode of travel to verify your identity (planes, trains) but not by immigration officials.